# Как развернуть мультисайт Wordpress локально учитывая что каждый из "подсайтов" привязан к своему домену?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-multisite

Как развернуть мультисайт Wordpress локально учитывая что каждый из "подсайтов" привязан к своему домену?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767561

Comment: "Локально" и "домены" как-то не сочетается.

Comment: @SeVlad почему? У меня куча доменов типа aaa.test

Comment: @KAGGDesign там мультисайт. (и развернуть, а не перенести)

Comment: @SeVlad ну и мультисайты на локалке так же живут